# Передать данные из request в переменную Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Есть простой тектовой файл с одной цифрой внутри, достаем его содержимое с помощью Axios (проект на Node.js, React), в консоль все выводится без проблем, подскажите как записать эту цифру в переменную?

```
function getValue(filepath) {
let value = null;

    axios.get(filepath)
                    .then(response => {
                        value = response.data;
                        console.log(response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

    return value;
}
```

Что сделать, чтобы функция вернула в value то, что находится в responce.data. Выдает либо unidentified либо пустоту...

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, метод `axios.get` возвращает [промис](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), а значит его выполнение происходит асинхронно. Соответственно, мы не можем просто вернуть его результат в вызвавшей его функции, т.к. на момент завершения работы функции метод может быть ещё не выполнен.

Решение – возвращать промис вместо значения:

```
function getValue(filepath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(filepath)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

После этого мы можем использовать функцию так:

```
getValue(path).then(value => {
    //тут переменная value будет доступна и заполнена
}).catch(error => {
    //если произоёдет ошибка при выполнении, она попадёт сюда
});
```

Comment: Не помогло, по сути тот же результат, в консоли есть, в переменной пусто. Может быть есть еще какие-то варианты получить данные из файла?

Comment: Не знаком с axios, но можно средствами самой ноды:

    var fs = require('fs'); 
    fs.readFile(path,function(err,data){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else{
            //data это string с содержимым файла
        }
    })

Answer (score 0):

Все равно undefined

```
getValueOfFile(filepath) {

let axios = require('axios');

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(filepath)
        .then(response => {
            resolve(response.data);
            console.log("Responce data".concat(response.data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        });
});
};


this.getValueOfFile(path).then(value => {
                cur_value = value;
                console.log("Value = ".concat(value));
            }).catch(error => {
                //если произоёдет ошибка при выполнении, она попадёт сюда
            });

        console.log("Cur_value = ".concat(cur_value));

        return cur_value;
```

Выдает в консоли:

```
Responce data1
Value = 1
Cur_value = undefined
```